# Negative Total Pressure in Ventilation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

I was doing my ventilation lab based on an exhaust fan in a tunnel and when I measured the total pressure I got a negative reading ( something to do with the static pressure being greater than the velocity pressure) can someone please explain this negative reading?

Comment: "Absolute" vs "Gauge" pressure sensor.

Comment: Please, provide some extra details. Anyway it's hard that you get a negative quantity from the sum of (static) pressure ($\gt 0$) and dynamic pressure (1/2 $\rho V^2 \ge 0$). Maybe it's just an offset value you're missing, maybe not. If you provide some more details, maybe anyone can get a better idea about what's happening

Comment: Most pressure gauges measure the _difference_ between the absolute pressures at two different points. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_measurement Even when a gauge is intended to show the absolute pressure at a single point, it may actually be measuring the difference between pressure at that one point and an evacuated space.

Answer (score 0):

Pressure readings often find the "gauge" pressure, which is the difference between the absolute current pressure and absolute ideal atmospheric pressure.  So a negative pressure reading on your gauge is really measuring "this much less than atmospheric pressure".

And the reason the pressure in your tunnel is negative should be fairly easy to work out.  The exhaust fan is removing air from the tunnel and sending it through the exhaust system.  Moving air typically has lower pressure than static air under similar conditions (Bernoulli's principle) .

Also, the exhaust fan is taking air from the room.  If the room stays the same volume, the temperature doesnt change, and air isnt being supplied as quickly as it is being taken out, the pressure must decrease (ideal gas law).

These are somewhat simplifications, since temperatures can change, and the compressibility of gas makes the Bernoulli principle less than straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

The fan is mounted to the exhaust point of ventilation (inducing or suction type) and makes the inside of tunnel under the ambient pressure. Othersize, the flow doesn't move. Therefore, the pressure in the tunnel is always negative.

Oick